# is there a way to add violation to multiple paths in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, constraints, custom-validators

is it possible to add a violation to multiple paths? like:

```
$this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->atPath('initialDate')
                    ->atPath('finalDate')
                    ->addViolation();
```

it only add to `initialDate`.

Comment: no, you need to build two times for the different violated path

Comment: Unfortunately a message is required for buildViolation. Even with an empty string passed this will add errors to the form field defined in path. The label will be red and an error with exclamation mark without message will appear. Removing the form_errors will also remove the label marked red. There seems to be no workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still add two violations with an empty message on the second

```php
$this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
    ->atPath('phone')
    ->addViolation()
;
$this->context->buildViolation('')
    ->atPath('email')
    ->addViolation()
;
```

but you will have the error markup generated also in the second field

[image: Multiple fields violated]

You can also override the `form_errors` block to adjust the markup if no message

```
{% block form_errors -%}
    {% if errors|length > 0 -%}
    {% if form.parent %}<span class="help-block">
    {% else %}<div class="alert alert-danger">{% endif %}
    <ul class="list-unstyled text-danger">
        {%- for error in errors if error.message -%}
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
                {{ error.message }}
            </li>
        {%- endfor -%}
    </ul>
    {% if form.parent %}</span>{% else %}</div>{% endif %}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock form_errors %}
```

Comment: By experiment, I confirm this also works in Drupal 8 (based on Symfony 3), and the empty message manifests itself similarly: There is a hardly-noticeable, empty message among the stack of actual messages when all messages are output simultaneously, but the fields are nicely highlighted as expected/desired.